# How to connect to database through laravel with ionic

Tags: php, database, angular, ionic-framework, connection

I'm new to Ionic and I'm having trouble getting data from a database in a server.

What I'm trying to do is to connect Ionic to the database in a server through a laravel app.

```
this.http
  .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/retrieve_data.php')
  .subscribe((data : any) =>
  {
     console.dir(data);
     this.items = data;
     console.log(this.items);
  },
  (error : any) =>
  {
     console.dir(error);
  });
```

Where retrieve_data.php is a file that contains the database connection and query, but nothing shows up in my app.

So I tried doing the same thing but with a local host. If I run the retrieve_data.php file directly from my browser it shows

> [{"id":1,"name":"Diego Rodriguez","email":"drodriguezm@fastfit.cl","password":"fastfit","remember_token":null}]

Which is the answer from the query to the db in the localhost. But when I try to do the same thing in Ionic like: `this.http.get('http://localhost/retrieve_data.php')` I get nothing.

Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong, you have to use laravel routes get data from the db. You don't need to create a new file to retrieve data from database, just edit the api.php file and add the routes you need like

```
Route::get('/users',function(){
User::get();
});
```

I solved my problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh there may be a problem with ionic, I had a while ago it has something to do with the cross-platform pull from the database.

You can run it and then debug on a device through google chrome and see if there is an error.

If it the cross-platform error ionic provides a solution whereby you use a proxy within the ionic app.